# Increase performance of ionic app

Tags: performance, cordova, ionic-framework

I created ionic app but its performance is too slow on android devices.
How can I increase performance of my app?
I have used list item, side menu and not performing any animation or transition.

Comment: Try chrome web view plugin.

Answer (score 2):

See, there are number of ways to improve performance of any ionic application.
I am facing the same thing and I did some research on google and I found very helping documents.

Some performance improvement techniques of them are as follows

**Use Track by**

> track by is used to avoid useless DOM manipulation when using
>   ng-repeat

Change your code from that:

```
ng-repeat="user in users"
```

to:

```
ng-repeat="user in users track by user.id"
```

(if users have a unique id) or

```
ng-repeat="user in users track by $index"
```

if they don’t. $index is added by ng-repeat to each elements of your collection.

**Use Loggers**

> Use loggers instead of `console.log` which decreases performance

**Use optimized Loops**

> Try to use cached for loop as possible as you can instead of angular
>   forEach.

**Use Native scrolling**

> Use native scrolling instead of JS scrolling.

Native scrolling can be enabled using `overflow-scroll=”true”` on your ion-content or using the `$ionicConfigProvider` provider:

```
angular.module('yourModule').config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
});
```

There are many more tips given in following links. Please refer them.

http://julienrenaux.fr/2015/08/24/ultimate-angularjs-and-ionic-performance-cheat-sheet/
http://tombuyse.com/improving-the-performance-of-your-ionic-application/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`collection-repeat="user in users track by $index"`

You can use `collection-repeat` to boost the scroll speed.